# How to access resolver context from mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql

I have graphql server running on node and express.
Now imagine a resolver function like this:

```
user(root, args, ctx) {
  return User.findOne({
    id: args.input.id,
  }, (err, existingUser) => {
    const user = existingUser;
    if (err) throw new Error('...');
    return user;
  });
},
```

Now I want to do some authorization. I save the authenticated user in `ctx.user`. Question: how can I pass the context to the Mongoose function? Mongoose only gives me two parameters, a `filter` and a `callback`. Do I need another layer of abstraction that talks to mongoose?

Comment: First of all, Mongoose supports promises for a long time, you're using legacy API. `if (err) throw new Error('...'); return user;` - this won't be handled properly, you cannot return or throw an error from regular callback, this is the same problem as here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . And the second thing is that you already have access to `ctx`. It's in the scope. You can do `ctx.user = ...`, can't you?

Comment: Sure in this scope I have access to ctx, but I want to handle authorization logic in my model and not in my resolver.